# AlarmManager Fires Immediately

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I am using this code and my AlarmManager fires immediately as the time passed to fire has still time to fire I am printing it on LOG so you can see.

```
public void SetAlarm(Context context, Date date, List<String> temp) {

    Log.d("Alarm Set", "Entered");
    Log.d("Alarm Set", date.getHours() + " " + date.getMinutes());

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
    i.putStringArrayListExtra("list", (ArrayList<String>) temp);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - 5);

    Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    long offset = rightNow.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET)
            + rightNow.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);
    long sinceMidnight = (rightNow.getTimeInMillis() + offset)
            % (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    long time_in_milis = (1000 * 60 * ((date.getHours() * 60) + date
            .getMinutes())) - sinceMidnight;
    Log.d("Alarm Time in Mili Seconds", "" + time_in_milis);

    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time_in_milis * 10000, pi);
}
```

Comment: I do not really see your problem

Comment: And your log says...?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your code correctly, you're calculating `time_in_milis` [sic] as a time difference, your desired time in relation to "right now". However, `set()` expects an absolute timestamp.

In other words, you're supplying a pretty low timestamp, effectively scheduling your alarm in the past.

For a simple test scenario, try passing `System.currentTimeMillis() + 60000` -- your alarm should fire about a minute later (remember that `set()` sets inexact alarms).